# How to get a DataRow from object

Tags: c#, class, object, datarow

I am trying to reuse some code from a project that works with DataRow instead of object. In my new project I have the model created and I work all with objects but Im trying to bring that piece of code since its very large. So the question is how can I get a DataRow from an object.

```cs
class Person
{
   public Int64 Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

Person p1 = new Person();
p1.Id = 1;
p1.Name = "John";

// How to get a DataRow from this p1 object

drPerson["Id"] == 1
drPerson["Name"] == John
```

I am looking for a way to get done it automatically if that is possible

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a `DataTable` to contain the row? If so just: `yourTable.NewRow()`

Comment: No I dont, the objects I am working with come from a complex sql sentence so I dont have a DataTable to work with. I know I could create one adding the columns myself but I wonder if there's an automatic way to do

Comment: It is possible you might find a library that does work for you, but probably you will just need to create it yourself. But, are you really sure you want to work with DataTables in the year 2022?

Comment: "How to get a DataRow from this p1 object" what do you mean? p1 doesn' t have any DataRow class

Comment: What I mean is how i get a DataRow that represents de data of p1

Comment: *I am looking for a way to get done it automatically* - use reflection to inspect the members of person and add columns to a datatable based on them. Add rows to the table based on the object values. Not something I'd like to do.. You could also look at serializing to XML and deserialziing to a datatable, though it's even more nasty of a hack

Comment: Instead tell us what you will use this datatable for and we'll perhaps suggest some alternatives

Comment: Actually, I wonder if @MarkPflug 's [Sylvan](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan) can help out here, binding to/reading from a List<Person> as a datareader and then a dataadapter could fill a datatable.. The other thought that occurred to me was to look at using binding to objects rather than databases in a strongly typed dataset..

Comment: @CaiusJard that reflection you are talking about sounds what I need. I'll give it a try and if i get it I will post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally thanks to the comments I got this code that works but it might be better

```cs
public static DataRow ToDataRow(object from) {

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      foreach(PropertyInfo property in from.GetType().GetProperties()) {
         DataColumn column = new DataColumn();

         column.ColumnName = property.Name;
         column.DataType = property.PropertyType;

         dt.Columns.Add(column);

      }

      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

      foreach(PropertyInfo property in from.GetType().GetProperties()) {
         dr[property.Name] = property.GetValue(from);
      }

      return dr;
}
```

With these code I can a DataRow with the name of the columns as the object atributes and also the values of it.

-- Edit

> Usually DataRow objects don't just hang out by themselves. They will belong to a DataTable. This method is creating a throwaway DataTable just to make a row. - siride

That is right so I've changed it to this

```cs
public static DataRow ToDataRow(object from, DataTable dt) {

      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

      foreach(PropertyInfo property in from.GetType().GetProperties()) {
         dr[property.Name] = property.GetValue(from);
      }

      return dr;
}

public static DataTable GetDataTable(object from) {

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

      foreach(PropertyInfo property in from.GetType().GetProperties()) {
         DataColumn column = new DataColumn();

         column.ColumnName = property.Name;
         column.DataType = property.PropertyType;

         dt.Columns.Add(column);

      }

      return dt;
}
```

With this change I can retrieve the DataTable before getting the DataRow and use both

Comment: Usually DataRow objects don't just hang out by themselves. They will belong to a DataTable. This method is creating a throwaway DataTable just to make a row. That is suspicious to me. Are you adding these rows to a table later? If so, you should consider a different approach.